# Android: Clear editText data from multiple Fragment at one Click

Tags: android, android-edittext, fragment

I am using `ScreenSlidePagerAdapter`, `ViewPager` and `PagerAdapter`
I have three fragments and every fragment contains three to four `editText` fields.
Fragment 1: `personalInfo`
Fragment 2: `contactInfo`
Fragment 3: `workInfo`
WorkInfo also contain `Clear Button` to clear all `editText` data form all three Fragmnets.

When user enter value in `personalInfo` then `contactInfo` and at last go to `WorkInfo`. 
Now at click of Clear button I want to clear all `editText` data.
I tried `findViewById()` but I could not get reference of `editText` from `Fragment 1` and `Fragment 2`.

If anyone has a solution then help me.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:
Make a boolean variable in your class initialized to false. When someone clicks on clear, change the value of that boolean to true. And in onstart() check this variable before showing data in edittext.

Comment: This will not work with fragment because when we move to 2nd fragment then onPause() of 1st fragment doesn't call. It call when we move to 3rd Fragment. In short, There are three fragments in Memory. One is current, second is Pervious and third is Next.

Comment: Yes, you are right. You can try creating an array of view, then clear the edittext of fragrment 2 from onclick listener. I think you can access edittext of fragment 2 from fragment 3 using view of fragment 2.

Answer (score 0):

Use an interface to communicate between fragments. You could read more about this from the Android Developer Docs.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

In resume, from your Fragment 3 you must call a method from your interface that must be implemetend by your activity. Then your activity must notify Fragment 1 and Fragment 2 to update their views.

Hope this help you.

Comment: This technique working only when fragments are in Memory but when we have 5 fragments then only 2 to 3 in memory. Other don't affect by this technique

Comment: The problem is that you don't have the reference to the other fragments? Try to use an [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) With it, you could fire an event from one fragment and listen to that event from the other fragments.